# TravelCheck.java Programming the check balance button

Tags: java, methods, joptionpane

I am trying to program the "Check balance" button to display the correct balance, by
using the getBalance() method in the Checks Class.

However I get the error message

TravelCheck.java:130: error: non-static method getBalance() cannot be referenced from a static context
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount of your checks total in US is" + Checks.getBalance(),
         ^

Anyone know how to correct this???

Heres a link to the instructions for my project

http://www.oakton.edu/user/2/somplski/c156/manual/csc156mp7.pdf

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TravelCheck extends JFrame
{
    private static final int WIDTH = 440, HEIGHT = 300;
    private JLabel Title, Instruct;
    private JButton pesoB, francB, euroB, usB, checkbalanceB, exitB;
    private ButtonHandler bHandler;

    public TravelCheck()
    {
        Title = new JLabel("Cash Your Traveler's Check ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Instruct = new JLabel("Click the button that matches your currency type", SwingConstants.CENTER);

        pesoB = new JButton(TravelString.PESO_S) ;
    bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    pesoB.addActionListener(bHandler);   

    francB = new JButton(TravelString.FRANC_S) ;
    bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    francB.addActionListener(bHandler);    

    euroB = new JButton(TravelString.EURO_S) ;
    bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    euroB.addActionListener(bHandler);   

    usB = new JButton(TravelString.US_S) ;
    bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
    usB.addActionListener(bHandler);    

    checkbalanceB = new JButton(TravelString.CHECK_S);
        bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
        checkbalanceB.addActionListener(bHandler);

    exitB = new JButton(TravelString.EXIT_S);
        bHandler = new ButtonHandler();
        exitB.addActionListener(bHandler);

    setTitle("Traveler's Check Machine");

    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,0));

    pane.add(Title);
    pane.add(Instruct);

    pane.add(pesoB);
    pane.add(francB);
    pane.add(euroB);
    pane.add(usB);
    pane.add(checkbalanceB);
    pane.add(exitB);

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public class TravelString
    {
    public static final String
    PESO_S = "Mexican peso",
    FRANC_S = "Swiss franc",
    EURO_S = "Euro dollar",
    US_S = "U.S. dollar",
    CHECK_S = "Check Balance",
    EXIT_S = "Exit";
    }

    private void transaction(String CurrencyString)
    {       
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The " + CurrencyString + " button was used",
                      "Button Message Demo", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }


    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.EXIT_S))
        System.exit(0);
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.PESO_S))
        transaction(TravelString.PESO_S);
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.FRANC_S))
        transaction(TravelString.FRANC_S);
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.EURO_S))
        transaction(TravelString.EURO_S);
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.US_S))
        transaction(TravelString.US_S);
        else if (e.getActionCommand().equals(TravelString.CHECK_S))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount of your checks total in US is" + Checks.getBalance(),
                          "Traveler's checks balance", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    }

    public class Checks
    {
    private static final double
        PESO = 2.0, FRANC = 3.0, EURO = 4.0;

    private int numberOfChecks;
    private int faceAmount;
    private String country;
    private double balance;

    public Checks (String s)
    {
        numberOfChecks = 0;
        faceAmount = 0;
        balance =  0.0;
        if (s.equals(TravelString.PESO_S) || s.equals(TravelString.FRANC_S) ||
        s.equals(TravelString.EURO_S) || s.equals(TravelString.US_S))
        country = s;
        else
        {
        country = TravelString.US_S;
        System.err.println("### Bad Checks constructor invocation. US Check by default ###");
        }
    }

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return numberOfChecks;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    public int getFace()
    {   
        return faceAmount;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deposit (int number, int denomination)
    {
        if (number > 0 && denomination > 0)
        {
        if (faceAmount == 0)
        {
        faceAmount = denomination;
        numberOfChecks = number;
        balance += faceAmount * number * conversion();
        }
        else if (faceAmount == denomination)
        {
        numberOfChecks += number;
        balance += faceAmount * number * conversion();
        }
        else
            System.err.println("### Non-existent denomination error in deposit() ###");
        }
        else
        System.err.println("### Non-positive parameter error in deposit() ###");        
    }

    public void withdrawal(int number)
    {
        if (number < 0)
        System.err.println("### Negative parameter error in withdrawal() ###");
        else if (balance < number * faceAmount * conversion())
        System.err.println("### Overdraw error in withdrawal() ###");
        else
        {
        numberOfChecks -= number;
        balance -= faceAmount * number * conversion();

        if (numberOfChecks == 0)
            faceAmount = 0;
        }
    }

    private double conversion()
    {
        double retval = 0.0;

        if (country.equals(TravelString.US_S))
        retval = 1.0;
        else if (country.equals(TravelString.PESO_S))
        retval = 1.0/PESO;
        else if (country.equals(TravelString.FRANC_S))
        retval = 1.0/FRANC;
        else if (country.equals(TravelString.EURO_S))
        retval = 1.0/EURO;
        return retval;
    }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    TravelCheck travelcheck = new TravelCheck();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You essentially need to call the Checks object's getBalance() method instead of statically calling it. Replace `Checks.getBalance()` with `ch.getBalance()` where `ch` is the object of the Checks class that was instantiated and passed onto the TravelCheck class.

To do this, you will have to create an object of the Checks class. Since Checks class is in the TravelCheck class, you could create an object inside the TravelCheck class's contructor (This is just an example. You should decide where you would ideally have the object created) :

```
public TravelCheck()
{
    Title = new JLabel("Cash Your Traveler's Check ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Instruct = new JLabel("Click the button that matches your currency type", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Checks ch=new Checks(TravelString.US_S); //Object creation with US currency variable passed in contructor
    ....
```

Then change the line 130 to reflect this change such that it uses this object :

```
OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The amount of your checks total in US is" + ch.getBalance(),
```

Comment: But the lines in question aren't in the Checks class. So  it won't work. He needs a reference to an instance of Checks.

Comment: @tiger apart from the above answer which is correct i suggest that you start reading basic java from any good book[head first java should be ideal for you] available out there

Answer (score 1):

You are calling Checks.getBalance(), to do that, Checks needs to be accessible without instantiating, means, it should be a static class and getBalance() function should also be static.

You do not have an object of the class Checks. Until you instantiate it, you will not have any values in  it. So create an object of it, then access the getBalance() function.

And any reason why you have a class inside a class ? Wouldn't it be easier to keep it outside to ensure re-usability ?